# Static route to access another IP/SUBNET from PC

Tags: windows, ip, subnet, route, static-routes

Maybe it's a simple concept misunderstand. I'm in a network with ip 172.16.0.xxx (mask 255.255.240.0).

How could I configure my PC (Windows 7) with a static route or any other kind of solution so I can access a specific device connected in the same network but with static ip address 192.168.0.10 (mask 255.255.255.0)?

I've tried route add with no success. It's a local configuration (only in my PC), I have no access to the router.

Comment: `How could I configure my PC (Windows 7) with a static route or any other kind of solution so I can access a specific device connected in the same network but with static ip address 192.168.0.10` - You can't. You could though temporarily assign an ip address in that subnet to your Windows 7 machine and access that device.

Comment: To add to joeqwerty's comment, those two devices aren't actually on the same network. Your network's IP range is 172.16.0.1-172.16.31.254. To contact anything outside that range, your device believes it needs to leave the network using it's gateway.